# Hyperledger enrollment error (node enrollAdmin.js): SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm a **novice** attempting to write my 1st hyperledger app.
I am following the instructions at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/write_first_app.html.
all appears to be working fine until I get to this:

> $ node enrollAdmin.js:
>   /home/mark/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:230
>    getChannel(name, throwError = true) {
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
>    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>    at Object. (/home/mark/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/index.js:25:18)
>    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)

Comment: Which version of Node.JS are you using?

Comment: $ nodejs --version  
v4.2.6

Comment: You need to upgrade Node to the latest 8.x version

Comment: 4.2.6 is the newest version:  
mark@TC1 ~/fabric-samples/composetest $ sudo apt-get install nodejs  
[sudo] password for mark:  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.2).

Comment: sorry, but i can't get a line-break no matter what i try!

Comment: UPDATE: i was able to update via the instructions at
https://joshtronic.com/2017/10/20/upgrade-to-nodejs-8-on-ubuntu-1710/

Comment: works now - THANK YOU, GARI !!

Comment: glad to hear it!